# Does the Struts2 tutorial have misnamed files? HelloWorldAction in HelloWorld.java

Tags: java, ant, struts2

I am going through the Struts2 tutorial at http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.html

They have a file `HelloWorld.java` that defines a class `HelloWorldAction` and the compiler (as run from ant) complains:

```
[javac] HelloWorld.java:6: class HelloWorldAction is public, should be declared in a file named HelloWorldAction.java
```

Obviously I can fix this, but is the tutorial really this wrong, or is there some configuration setting that I am missing?  I already fixed this once with the tutorial having class `MessageStore` defined in Message.java and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: As an opinion, if you are going to invest your time learning a Java MVC framework I would spend my time learning Spring MVC. Struts is on the way out.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown. Not at all, since this is Struts2, not Struts. Spring MVC is more popular in North America nowadays, while it is not in Asia, for example. And with Convention plugin and jQuery plugin, it has nothing to envy to Spring MVC (unit testing apart, that is less easy). It also has a lot of stuff ready out-of-the-box, that in Spring you have to handle by yourself. The truth is that Struts2 is paying the cost of having the same name of its predecessor, although it has very few things in common with it.

Comment: It's a typo; geez. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caption says

> Step 2 - Create The Action Class HelloWorldAction.java

So just rename the file that's probably the typo. There are no such config. Java always wants you to name files accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is wrong. You need to name it HelloWorldAction.java

[image]

```
public class Foo
```

must always be named `Foo.java` no matter what framework you are using or javac will complain.